# Video streaming with ipCamera in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ffmpeg

I am developing app for the connecting ip camera and get stream. I don't know how to convert stream into video. I have analysed, and then i tried FFMPEG library. But i did not get correct url for ios with FFMPEG.  Can you suggest the guide for implementation.

Now i am integrating ffmpeg, when i integrated i got the error when opening avformat_find_stream_info() function. I used the increase or less the value of pFormatCtx->max_analyze_duration. But no solution for this.

[mjpeg @ 0x8b85000] max_analyze_duration 1000 reached at 40000
   [mjpeg @ 0x8b85000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Pls help how to solve this.

Comment: Hi Brother do you find any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "AVCam" example from Apple.
It does exactly that, and with lots of inline comments.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Here is a small code snippet that will point you in the right direction:

Create an AVCaptureSession first...

```
            // Init the device inputs
AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self backFacingCamera] error:nil];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *newAudioInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self audioDevice] error:nil];


// Setup the still image file output
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *newStillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                nil];
[newStillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[outputSettings release];


// Create session (use default AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh)
AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
```

Create the video file output

```
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *aMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
if ([aSession canAddOutput:aMovieFileOutput])
[aSession addOutput:aMovieFileOutput];
```

Save the file:

```
-(void)recorder:(AVCamRecorder *)recorder recordingDidFinishToOutputFileURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([[self recorder] recordsAudio] && ![[self recorder] recordsVideo]) {
        // If the file was created on a device that doesn't support video recording, it can't be saved to the assets 
        // library. Instead, save it in the app's Documents directory, whence it can be copied from the device via
        // iTunes file sharing.
        [self copyFileToDocuments:outputFileURL];

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:[self backgroundRecordingID]];
        }       

        if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerRecordingFinished:)]) {
            [[self delegate] captureManagerRecordingFinished:self];
        }
    }
    else {  
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                        if (error) {
                                            if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManager:didFailWithError:)]) {
                                                [[self delegate] captureManager:self didFailWithError:error];
                                            }                                           
                                        }

                                        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
                                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:[self backgroundRecordingID]];
                                        }

                                        if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerRecordingFinished:)]) {
                                            [[self delegate] captureManagerRecordingFinished:self];
                                        }
                                    }];
        [library release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this about remote camera (IP camera?) source? I think that's what the original poster and I were looking for.